# Is there a way to select shape keys via geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a setup using geometry nodes that will cycle through an object's different shape keys using an integer slider - is it currently possible to reference the shape keys in Geometry nodes or would it need to be baked into an attribute first?

[image]

I basically want it to work similarly to how it currently works in the shape keys tab when the Pin icon is selected:

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

[image]